# c# understanding the bool expression

Tags: c#, boolean-logic

This is a really simple question I am sure, but I cannot figure out why this assertion fails...

basically if IsApple is false or IsBannana is false assertion should fail, however if one of the two is true assertion should pass, could anyone explain why this assertain fails?

```
        [Test]
        public void IsApplesOrBannans()
        {
            bool IsApple = true;
            bool IsBannana = false;

            if (!IsApple || !IsBannana)
                Assert.Fail();

            Assert.Pass();
        }
```

Comment: `#ifdef MERRIAM_WEBSTER // static const bool IsBannana = false; // #endif` - ....

Comment: You contradict yourself, you say 'if either is false it should fail, but if either is true it should pass'. You need to be clearer on this logic

Comment: I know I contradicted myself, but I was trying to work out why my logic was incorrect... that was the point of my question...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're saying makes no sense.

Here's how I (and the compiler) understand what you're saying:

> basically if IsApple is false or IsBannana is false assertion should fail

- If IsApple is false the assertion should fail
- If IsBanana is false, the assertion should fail

In other words, if one of them is false, you *don't care* whether or not the other is also false.

> however if one of the two is true assertion should pass

- If one of them is true, you *don't care* whether the other one is also true.

Those requirements contradict each others.

Perhaps you meant "if IsApple is false **AND** IsBanana is false"; that is, if they are *both* false.

But what you wrote was "if IsApple is false **OR** IsBanana is false", that is, if *one of them* are false.

Comment: thanks, very clear but Erno answered earlier and I understood from him what went wrong! I have upvoted you :)

Comment: thanks for the head up... I actually picked the first one that made the most sense to me, not the first one perse :) I only needed that bit of info to figure out where I went wrong, but I do agree looking at your answer will really help someone in the same situation...

Answer (score 4):

The assert will fail if EITHER is false, it will only pass if BOTH are true.

Edit: I would re-write this as:

```
if (IsApple || IsBanana)
{
    Assert.Pass();
}
else
{
    Assert.Fail();
}
```

Interestingly, the question as posed cannot be answered (since if one is true and the other is false according to the question the expected result is amiguous).

Comment: @Haroon: Try reading about De Morgan: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws

Answer (score 4):

`!IsBannana` is true so the if evaluates to true.

I bet you wanted:

```
if(!IsApple && !IsBananna)
    Assert.Fail();
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted... man how I feel so stupid for not getting it, I would like to say is it ok if I delete this question and we never speak of it :)

Comment: Nah, leave it for the future generations so they can feel beter than we were.

Comment: At the time of answering, your answer was the most clear, a few other people updated afterwards so I will give it to you- lol thanks :) (will have to wait a few moments though)

Comment: +1, short and to the point. :) As @Erno says, never delete your questions. Leave it so the next guy can avoid making the same mistakes. ;) Ideally, people should be able to find answers to their question here on SO *immediately*, without having to ask a question first. Sooner or later, someone else is going to have the same problem, and then they should be able to benefit from your question and the answers you got. :)

Comment: @Haroon, thanks but don't worry about picking the answer that was the fastest; pick the one that answered the question. Stack Overflow is not a race for the fastest reply, it is a quest for the best answer.

Comment: I sometime envision my kids (and their kids) searching the web for an answer and ending up with the answer I gave today. To them: If you are still struggling with this problem, lean back and smile, think of me just as I am thinking of you now. Then pick up another trade: either software development hasn't progressed a lot or you are not cut out for it ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Do this instead:

```
if(!IsApple && !IsBannana)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your pass condition is `IsApple || IsBannana`, so your fail condition can be written as:

```
if (!(IsApple || IsBannana))
```

Or alternatively you can say both must be false to fail:

```
if ((IsApple==false) && (IsBannana==false))
```

Which usually is written as:

```
if (!IsApple && !IsBannana))
```

Personally I think the first of these three alternatives is the best. But that's just a stylistic choice. functionally they are equivalent.

Or even better, you could switch your `then` and `else` part of the `if`:

```
public void IsApplesOrBannans()
{
    bool IsApple = true;
    bool IsBannana = false;

    if (IsApple || IsBannana)
        Assert.Pass();
    else
        Assert.Fail();            
}
```

Or even throw out the `if` statement entirely:

```
public void IsApplesOrBannans()
{
    bool IsApple = true;
    bool IsBannana = false;

    Assert.IsTrue(IsApple || IsBannana);
}
```

Comment: @Stephan the condition in his code doesn't fit hit textual description. You assume the code is right. But as I understand it the text is right and the OP wants to know why the code is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your pass condition contradicts your fail condition, because if only one is true, the other one is false and thus fulfills the fail condition.

if you want it to make sense, change it to this:

```
if (!IsApple && !IsBanana)
    Assert.Fail():
```

or, if you also don't want it to be an apple and banana at the same time

```
if (IsApple == IsBanana)
    Assert.Fail():
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(!A|| !A) = !!(!A || !B) = !(A && B) = !(true && false) --> false
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        if (IsApple != IsBannana)
            Assert.Fail();
```

I think this trick `!=` is a C# FAQ as *poor man's XOR*

Answer (score 0):

You dont want the case where neither a nor b is false, or rather at least one should be true, so

```
   [Test]      
    public void IsApplesOrBannans() 
    {      
       bool IsApple = true;     
       bool IsBannana = false;    
       if (!(IsApple || IsBannana))   
            Assert.Fail();        
       Assert.Pass();       
    }
```